# Ubuntu won't shutdown (stuck on "Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules")

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, shutdown, xampp

When try to shutdown the computer it stays on a "Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules" message. It looks like it has to do something with VirtualBox, but happens even if I didn't use VirtualBox at all. Also it happens randomly.

This is what I see on the screen.

```
The system is going down for halt now
* Stopping TiMidity++ ALSA MIDI Emulation...
hecking for running unattended-upgrades:
* Stopping UPnP devices daemon minissdpd
minissdpd[1194]: received signal 15, good bye
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules
```

And it stays here forever if I don't do the "force power-off".

My specs: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Dell Studio 1555 Laptop

Comment: Try reinstalling VirtualBox guest additions, seems like it's freezing because something went wrong in the kernel installation. If you get an error or a warning while installing, post here.

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep vbox`? If there is some output, try `sudo rmmod ARG` where `ARG` is the first word in the above `lsmod` output? If this happens without any error messages please paste the file `/etc/init.d/virtualbox-ose` to some place and post the link to the file.

Comment: Output of lsmod: _http://pastebin.com/mLWAFu9Q_ Insted of virtualbox-ose (I don't have this file) I uploaded /etc/init.d/virtualbox file here: _http://wikisend.com/download/908294/virtualbox_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found out what's causing this. It must be Apache or something, because if I stop xampp before shutdown, it all goes well. Unbelievable.

Comment: well...that means the problem is solved for me...

Comment: Since there will be no more answers, think your answer is the right one, stopping xamp didn't work for me, though.

Comment: @EvandroSilva Could you try to `rmmod` to modules as described above? What happens?

Comment: @qbi `Module vboxsf is in use`, `Module vboxguest is in use by vboxsf`.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `lsmod | grep vbox` somewhere? Thanks.