# After updates sometimes experience stutter, lag and high load on CPU

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel, mouse, cpu-load

After 10 January (meltdown patches) I've started sometimes experience 1 second stutter. My audio stutter and maybe video as well but it is hard to notice, mouse cursor lagging as if experiencing high load on HDD and during this 1 second I have high load on CPU.
I managed to make a screenshot of KSysGuard during(or aftermath of) that 1 second:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMIZg.png

If I turn off the Wi-Fi or connect to the Wi-Fi network problem disappears.
Just in case, here is the wireless info - https://paste.ubuntu.com/26484280/

I've tried Linux kernel 4.10.0-43 and there was no problem. Any kernel from 4.13.0-26 and up to the 4.16.4 have this problem because I've tested many kernels on different distributions.

Distro: Xubuntu 16.04.3
Kernel: 4.13.0-32

This is a bug in the kernel but I don't know how to specifically report it.

Comment: You can simply keep using **kernel 4.10-0-42**  and keep checking into **4.13.0-xx** series until it is fixed. Or you can try newest kernels with Meltdown / Spectre fixes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Comment: tried 4.14.17 and 4.15.1 nothing changed.

Comment: You'll have to remove both 4.14.17 and 4.15.1 so kernel 4.13.0-33 is auto-installed when it comes out. Then boot with 4.10.0-42 for day to day use. File a bug report against 4.13.0-32 at launchpad.net. You can also look at `systemd-analyze blame` and `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` for error messages that you might be able to fix.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thank you. I've updated issue. I don't know for what I should looking in a `systemd-analyze blame` and `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` because I'm not that savvy.

Comment: The bug may have fixed by now. What kernel version are you using now? Use `uname -r` in the terminal to find out.

Comment: Today I've tested on a 4.13.0-39.44(Ubuntu), 4.13.0-40.45(Ubuntu, **using now**), 4.15(Ubuntu 18.04) 4.15.18(stable EOL), 4.16.4 and on a Fedora 27

Comment: This is how you report a bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210967/how-to-report-a-system-bug