# Mi Notebook Pro (Ubuntu 20.04) does not turn back on after lid open

Tags: 20.04, suspend, intel-graphics, lid

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) on my new Mi Notebook Pro (14", Core-i5, 16/512GB, Iris Xe graphics). It does suspend when the lid is closed but not turning back on once the lid is opened. I tried everything I could, like tweaking the logind.conf file from `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` where I uncommented the `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend`. It seems like it does not have any effect. What could be the problem?

Comment: You may have found a bug. See [How to report a system bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210967/how-to-report-a-system-bug) and file a bug report.

Comment: Do you have a swap partition or file in use? `free` will tell you.