# Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Live USB) Crashes After Installing Updates

Tags: 22.04, live-usb, update-manager, thinkpad

After installing the updates available on December 11, 2022 (Pacific Standard Time), the computer crashes and says:

```
[0.116630] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[0.116630] x86/cpu: SGX virtualization disabled due to lack of VMX.
```

Things Tried:

- Restarting the computer
- Reporting a problem to Ubuntu using the Ubuntu bug report program (GUI). They say "Could not determine the package or source package name."

Steps to Reproduce the Problem:

1. Download the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS ISO from [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com).
2. Put it on a USB drive using Rufus.
3. Plug USB drive into a powered-off ThinkPad.
4. Press power button on ThinkPad.
5. Immediately mash the Enter key until you can ask the computer to show the Boot Options menu.
6. Tell the computer to show the Boot Options menu.
7. Tell the computer to boot from the USB drive.
8. Press Enter when Ubuntu asks how to boot.
9. Wait for the Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen to appear.
10. Click "Try Ubuntu".
11. Connect to a WiFi network.
12. Press the Windows key on the keyboard.
13. Type "update".
14. Click the middle search result labeled "Software Updater".
15. Click Install Now
16. Wait a while.
17. Watch the computer show a spinning circle animation.
18. Wait up to 15 minutes

To See More Information:

- Between steps 11 and 12, plug in an external display.
- After step 18, you will see text on the laptop's internal display ("[0.116630] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS", "[0.116630] x86/cpu: SGX virtualization disabled due to lack of VMX.").

System That Created the USB Drive:

- Windows 10 (Version 21H2)
- Rufus 3.21.1949

USB Drive:

- SanDisk Extreme PRO
- 128 GB

System That Tried To Boot Ubuntu:

- Lenovo ThinkPad P53

[image: Photo of the computer and external display]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to report a system bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210967/how-to-report-a-system-bug)

Comment: Are you seeking support?  or trying to report a bug.  Your *support question* reads more like a bug report to me, and this isn't a bug tracker. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for details on reporting bugs, but if you have trouble with the `ubuntu-bug` tools, you can always file the report online with launchpad, then add additional details using `apport-collect` later from the impacted box (*this would appear to get around the problem picking a package somewhat as you're selecting that online with a browser yourself*).

Comment: Doing an update/upgrade on an Ubuntu Persistent USB will quickly fill the persistence file or partition. Once full the USB will no longer boot. Easiest thing is to reinstall Ubuntu using Rufus, make the persistent partition large and resist the temptation to update/upgrade. This used to be a big problem when there was a casper-rw file size limit of 4GB.