# Extensive problems with Hyper-V Quick Create 22.04 image. Can I report bugs? Should I use something else?

Tags: xrdp, hyper-v

The 22.04 image installed via Hyper-V Quick Create seems to be riddled with problems.

1. Should I be using another approach to run Ubuntu in Windows? WSL2 is not suitable for my needs (and is similarly rough anyway).
2. Is it possible to report bugs anywhere? The usual channels are very much about particular packages, but this is on a distribution level.
   The issues include:

   - Apt and snaps fill the disk after a couple of days of automatic updates.
   - Constant popups about systemd `SIGABRT`s and `xrdp` crashes.
   - Snap auto-updates pop up in gnome but cannot install because gnome is using them.
   - `xrdp` file shares cache out of date info.
   - `xrdp` file shares are inauthentic, don't work with docker volume mounts.
   - `xrdp` sessions don't cache sudo passwords.
   - `gnome-control-center` cannot apply some settings, such as ethernet ipv4 settings, in an `xrdp` session because it doesn't consistently sudo.
   - Hostnames only work intermittently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to report a system bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210967/how-to-report-a-system-bug)

Comment: Did you try reading the online bug reporting documentation?  ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  You can get some assistance at helping you find the package to file against (*though you note many already*) using IRC, telegram, & other type means

Comment: @guiverc I have no evidence these bugs exist within any particular package; I only know they exist in the way the image integrates & configures the system - and I haven't found a package (or maintainer info) for the system image.

Comment: If it's related to how the image boots then it'll be an issue with the image/ISO itself, if it's now it installs/configures then it's the installer.. Neither of those systems relate to `xrdp` or `gnome-control-center` as they just boot then install the system.. ie. the components matter so the correct team can deal with it. If it's an official Ubuntu 22.04 image there are >25 such images (not counting unofficial images from elsewhere than https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) with images for server, desktop, different architectures & even *flavors* & point releases.

Comment: This isn't an installer image; it's already configured, with no sign of the installer running at all.

Comment: As far as I am aware it is an official image, but it is preinstalled in Hyper-V and labelled as authored by "Canonical Group Ltd", rather than being distributed on an image mirror.

Comment: If it's not an image download from ubuntu.com, you likely should report the bug with the provider of that image, and they can them *upstream* the bug to Ubuntu or where they get/create it as they'll know the source. I'm a desktop user myself and thus aren't very familiar with all the various images, but am aware there are official & unofficial provided from different sources.. If it's an official image I can explore the *seed* file that leads to its creation; this cannot be done for unofficial (*you need to check with the creator*)

Comment: Thank you for that. After some more searching I did find a Canonical project on GitHub, so I've raised an issue there. (https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-desktop-hyper-v/)