# Interface Drops after Kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, interface

I have an ubuntu server with 22.04 and yesterday I updated the kernel version from 5.15.0-97-generic to 6.5.0-18-generic and after upgrade i have seen interface drops and also there was tcp disconnection for customers. Then I rolled back the kernel version back to 5.15 and it solved the issue. Could this be a bug in the kernel? anyone face this issue earlier ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to report a system bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210967/how-to-report-a-system-bug)

Comment: If the kernel is the only thing different, please file a `ubuntu-bug linux` . Please also include which NIC you are using